# download SSL Certificate in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, ssl

In linux server what is the command to list all the SSL certificate and how to download SSL Certificate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What certificate do you want to list and which one do you need to download? Anyway, the answer to your question might be `openssl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.de:443 </dev/null
```

Gets you the text representation of which you can convert/rebundle to your liking. It may output more than one certificate (and it will also output part of the data stream), but in any case, it works. Quite useful if the certs are not otherwise offered in obvious fashion by the authority.

Comment: In addition, complete command to download the certificate : `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.de:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -out google.pem`